# How can I use the "Your latest posts" as a template?

Tags: posts

Which is to say, I want a page that shows the content of "Your latest posts".

To understand what I mean by "You latest posts" go to:

**Settings** > **Reading** > **Front page displays** and one of the options is "Your latest posts".

A page needs a template, but rather than code it myself using the API (which I have done, albeit poorly) I would like to just use logic that is already existing, particularly with the pagination.

Comment: What is »Your latest posts« exactly?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: I see, sorry, could have figured that, but wasn't sure. Generally, you set a static page to be your blog posts page. It will use the `home.php` template, if available, to show the posts or it uses the `index.php` template - see in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display). So I would recommend to create a `home.php` template and make it fit your needs. Thats pretty much it, there is not really a lot more existing logic to use.